# jQuery .valid() throws error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

In my JavaScript function sometimes `$(args._postBackElement).valid()` throws error because it is not a valid input element. Is there any way to check whether `.valid()` can be called for that element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do -

```
$(args._postBackElement).length
```

to see if the element existed, or -

```
$(args._postBackElement).is(":input")
```

to see if it's an input element.